# Trying to create method which returns multiple strings from a string[]

Tags: java, junit5

I need to create a method which searches the String array for instances of "string1" and "string2" then capitalizes them.

Below is a test for that method.

The lesson is about streams and lambdas. I had already created similar methods for 8 previous tests, but for this one I got no idea to go with.

```
@Test
public void testMap() throws Exception {
    String[] sentence = "A long sentence of strings. string1 is repeated twice and so is a string2...".split("\\.");
    assertEquals("[STRING1, STRING1, STRING2, STRING2]", ClassWithMethods.getString1andString2(sentence).toString());

}
```

Comment: The question is: is the test wrong or is the implementation wrong. We can hardly say without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: That is *your* assignment, *you* have to do the work. We can help you with *specific* problems, not with your entire homework assignment.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Please check my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to certain solution, it passes the test.
Any criticism is welcome, thanks.

```
public static List<String> getString1andString2(String[] sentence) {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(sentence);
    return list.stream().map(x -> x.replace(" ", "")).filter(x -> x.equalsIgnoreCase("string1") || x.equalsIgnoreCase("string2")).map(String::toUpperCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```